# What's the most appropriate way to share data between OAuth 2.0 authorization and resource server?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

We currently have a website with the following structure:

- the back-end is in Drupal 10 and it acts both as resource owner and authorization servers for the users, via the [simple_oauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth) module, which implements the OAuth 2.0 standard
- a decoupled React-front that authenticates the users with the end-point provided by the above module, using OAuth 2.0 standard

Now, we need to integrate this stack with an external learning management system.

The existing react front-end needs to show part of the data provided by the LMS directly in the existing site - e.g. the list of courses already bought by the user.
On other hand, it needs to redirect to the LMS for other functions - e.g. an actual course page with video\exercices.

I couldn't manage to find some good examples on what is a suggested flow\architecture to manage the communication between the two "back-ends".

My possible ideas for now are:

1. The front-end call both the Drupal back-end and the LMS back-end to get the necessary data.
   It also requires the authentication for both back-ends: when the user land on a page containing data of the LMS, eventually there's a redirect to it. The LMS let the user log in with the Drupal user credentials. LMS take care to sync the "drupal" user with is own and to expose the data to the front-end.
   The biggest cons of this implementation I can see is that the user needs to log in twice.
2. The front-end interact only with the Drupal back-end.
   It's the latter to provide all the LMS data, calling the API provided by the LMS, and taking care to synchronize the Drupal's users with the LMS' users.
   The biggest cons I can see of this implementation is that it's necessary to duplicate pretty much every end-point provided by the LMS into the Drupal instance.

Neither of those implementations seems smooth to me, and therefore I wonder if I'm missing some Oauth2 pattern that could help on this kind of stack.

For example: the react-front, being already authenticate, could pass the oauth "access" and "refresh" token directly to the LMS, and the latter use them to authenticate against the Drupal back-end? Would that be a security risk?